# How to extract the numerical value of a dynamical variable

Tags: dynamic

I want to inspect interactively an image by selecting points by the mouse pointer. This is easily done by `LocatorPane` - here is a simplified example:

```
plot = ListPlot[{{1, 1}}];
Manipulate[
  x = Dynamic[First[pt]];
  LocatorPane[Dynamic[pt], 
     Show[plot, Epilog -> {Red, PointSize[Large], Point[Dynamic[pt]],
     Text[Style[StringForm["x = `1`", x], Blue, 20], {1, 1.5}]}]],
  {{pt, {0, 0}}, None}
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Now imagine that for a selected point I would like to get the numerical value of the x-coordinate. I would like to calculate a function of it (like divide by 3) and/or save its numerical value to an external data file. This does not work because the x is a dynamical object. How to extract the current numerical value of x? In addition to solving this particular problem I would like to understand better how does Dynamic really work.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use [`Setting`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Setting.html): it replaces dynamic content (controllers, `Dynamic` objects, etc.) with its setting.

```
Button["Get x!", Print[FullForm@Setting@x]]
```

Comment: Great thanks! And sorry - I was looking for this sort of a function but I missed it - shame on me.

Comment: @Marek I think it is an important question and I was surprised that it was never before asked here in Mathematica.SE.

Comment: It doesn't works in version 12.

Answer (score 14):

I think @IstvanZachar's answer works fine but it's more complex than it seems at first sight, so don't take it lightly :P

It does something "smart" to leak a cell local variable `pt` to the outside.
`x` is global and it stores the current name of the kernel's copy of the local `pt`, so you can access it from other cells.

An "easier" (conceptually) solution, that feels more natural to me is to simply not make `pt` local. Or, if you want the value of `First@pt` stored in `x`

```
plot = ListPlot[{{1, 1}}];
Manipulate[DynamicWrapper[
  LocatorPane[Dynamic[pt], 
   Show[plot, 
    Epilog -> {Red, PointSize[Large], Point[Dynamic[pt]], 
      Text[Style[StringForm["x = `1`", x], Blue, 20], {1, 1.5}]}]],
  x = First@pt], {{pt, {0, 0}}, None}]
```

and then just use `x` knowing it has the updated value and no `Dynamic` bothering