# How to extract value from dynamic list?

Tags: dynamic

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to extract the numerical value of a dynamical variable](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/15090/how-to-extract-the-numerical-value-of-a-dynamical-variable)
>   [Dynamic wraps a list that I cannot extract values from](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/17662/dynamic-wraps-a-list-that-i-cannot-extract-values-from)

I want to extract value from list dynamically,this is my code

```
xData = {"Environment", "Building"};
DynamicModule[{}, 
 Row[{tabP1 = 
    Dynamic[Position[xData, ToString[buttonValue]], 
     t = tabP1[[1, 1]]]}]]
Button[button1, buttonValue = Environment] Button[button2, 
  buttonValue = Building]
```

It gives `{{1}}` or `{{2}}` based on button i have clicked. Now i want to extract value(1) from this list(`{{1}}`) . I have tried to extract it as follows `t=tabP1[[1,1]]` but t has list(`{{1}}`) not value(1). I need value instead of list.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Same topic, but in this case I could see what the OP's problem is.

Comment: @Michael that's a good point; maybe both should be closed as a duplicate of http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/15090/121 ?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Fair enough.  That answer works here, although the OPs' misconceptions about `Dynamic` seem different.

Answer (score 2):

I'm a little unclear about the exact functionality you seek.  Below is an example that has the desired effect you describe.  It may not be exactly how one would do it in the context of a larger project.

You need to have the assignments inside (the first argument of) the `Dynamic`.  The second argument should be a function and is used primarily in interactive controls (`Slider`, `InputField`, etc., but not `Row`).  When the variables in the first `Dynamic` expression change (`buttonValue`), the expression is reevaluated, making the assignments happen.

```
xData = {"Environment", "Building"};
buttonValue = "Environment";
DynamicModule[{}, 
 Row[{Dynamic[tabP1 = Position[xData, buttonValue]; t = tabP1[[1, 1]]; tabP1]]}]]
 Button["button1", buttonValue = "Environment"] Button["button2", 
  buttonValue = "Building"]
```

I made a couple of other changes (initialized `buttonValue`, changed names to strings -- consider them suggestions), but left some other oddities alone.  In particular, the `Button`s are multiplied.  I would guess you want to use `Row`, or you're just testing and didn't care that much.

Other suggestions go beyond the question:  You can put the `Dynamic` around the whole `Row` instead of the first element, but that may depend on what else you might add to the row.  You can put it all in one `Manipulate`.  The assignment to `tabP1` and `t` can be done via each button's action:

```
updateTab[key_] := (tabP1 = Position[xData, key]; t = tabP1[[1, 1]]);
Button["button1", updateTab["Environment"]] Button["button2", 
  updateTab["Building"]]
```