# Getting value of clock

Tags: syntax

I have the following code:

```
a = Dynamic[Floor[Clock[2]]] (*So this basically alternates between 0 and 1*)
If[a==1, Print["true"]]
```

But this doesn't work, it instead prints the following `If[a==0, Print["true"]]` and then changes to `If[a==1, Print["true"]]` and then back.

How can I get the value from the clock?

Comment: Related: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/2972/121

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, looking at the other answers, I am not sure if I correctly understand what you want. But I'll give it a go:

```
a = Dynamic[Floor[Clock[2]]](*same thing*)
Dynamic[If[Setting@a == 1, "true", "false"]]
```

Does this yield what you wanted? The problem in your case is, that `a` is no "plain" integer, see `FullForm[a]`. Thus, the test `a==1` is not executing. Using `Setting` lets you retrieve the value of a `Dynamic` var, see e.g. here: [Dynamic Values](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/15090/how-to-extract-the-numerical-value-of-a-dynamical-variable)

Answer (score 1):

Well, the problem locates in the difference between **Equal** and **SameQ**.
When **Equal** can't determin whether the args are equal or not, it returns the expression back with no changes. What you really need is **SameQ** here, and the code looks like this:

```
a = Dynamic[Floor[Clock[2]]] (*So this basically alternates between 0 and 1*)If[a === 1, Print["true"]]
```