# Plotting a dynamical NonlinearModelFit Function

Tags: plotting, dynamic, fitting

Currently I'm playing around with dynamics and the [`NonlinearModelFit`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/NonlinearModelFit.html) function.
To be precise, I want to fit a function the data, which range I want to specify dynamically. This is not a problem and works fine. But when it comes to plotting, Mathematica refuses to show me anything.

Here's an example code (the testdata consists of 100 values. The variable min gives the lower bound for the fit to begin. )

---

```
min = 50;

testdata = Table[{x*RandomReal[{0.95, 1.05}], 3 x^2 + 4 x}, {x, 0, 10, 0.1}];

fit = Dynamic[NonlinearModelFit[testdata[[min ;;]], a x^2 + b x, {a, b}, x]];

Dynamic[Plot[fit[x], {x, 0, 4}]];
```

---

Do you have an idea, how to overcome this problem?

Thanks in advance,
Juergen

Comment: Thx for the reply! I think i should have mentioned, what my intention was with the use of Dynamic. In the huge notebook-file I have, i want to evaluate the dynamic value "min" and all plots, functions etc. which depends on "min" and are declared as "Dynamic" should be instantaneous refreshed.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently I misinterpreted this question.  My old answer is preserved below for reference.

I now believe you want something like this:

```
min = 50;

testdata = Table[{x*RandomReal[{0.95, 1.05}], 3 x^2 + 4 x}, {x, 0, 10, 0.1}];

fit := NonlinearModelFit[testdata[[min ;;]], a x^2 + b x, {a, b}, x];

Dynamic[
 Refresh[Plot[fit[x], {x, 0, 4}, Evaluated -> True], TrackedSymbols -> {min}]
]
```

You should get a Dynamic plot that updates when the value of `min` is changed.  Note that the `fit` definition has been changed to `SetDelayed` and `Plot` is using the (undocumented) `Evaluated -> True` option to effect that evaluation (inside the `Dynamic`).  [`Refresh`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Refresh.html) was needed to get specific updating, and [`TrackedSymbols`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/TrackedSymbols.html) was used to keep the refresh from happening excessively.

---

You're not using `Dynamic` correctly.  `Dynamic` is only for display; it should not be given as input to a function.  Please see:

- [How can I compare a dynamic variable with a literal in Mathematica?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/2972/121)
- [How to extract the numerical value of a dynamical variable](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/15090/121)

Try this instead:

```
testdata = Table[{x*RandomReal[{0.95, 1.05}], 3 x^2 + 4 x}, {x, 0, 10, 0.1}];

Manipulate[
 With[{fit = NonlinearModelFit[testdata[[min ;;]], a x^2 + b x, {a, b}, x]},
  Plot[fit[x], {x, 0, 4}]
 ],
 {min, 1, 100, 1}
]
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply and your solution! But this is not exactly, what I'm looking for. As posted above to the other user, I'm trying to dynamically set the value of the variable min somewhere in my notebook-file. And upon setting min to the new value, I want all plots/functions which depend on "min" to be changed at the same time.

Comment: @Bobu I'm sorry, I didn't see your comment until now.  The message notification system here is very unreliable.  I have updated my answer now; please let me know if this is doing what you want.

Answer (score 1):

Here my attempt with minimal changes to your code:

```
fit := NonlinearModelFit[testdata[[min ;;]], a x^2 + b x, {a, b}, x];

Dynamic[Plot[Evaluate@fit[x], {x, 0, 4}]]
```

Now the NonlinearModelFit is performed every time `min` is changed.

Don't forget to include `Evaluate` in your plot.