# How can I save a Manipulate's control settings to a dataset?

Tags: manipulate, dataset

This is probably an extremely simple question. I have a manipulate that sets variables used to define an offset, amplitude, frequency and phase of a trigonometric function.

```
Manipulate[
  Module[{Vac,Vdc, ω, ϕ, f},
    Vac = ctrlVac;                      (* AC Voltage *)
    Vdc = ctrlVdc;                      (* DC Offset *)
    f = ctrlf;                          (* Frequency *)
    ω = 2 π f;
    ϕ = ctrlPhi;                        (* Phase Offset *)
    gFunc = ctrlgFunc;                  (* Function *)
    Plot[ Vdc + Vac  gFunc[ ω t + ϕ],{t,0, 0.4}]],
  {{ctrlgFunc,Sin,""},{Sin,Cos, Tan, Cot }},Delimiter,
  {{ctrlVac,1.5,Subscript["V","ac"]}, -10,10},
  {{ctrlVdc, 0.5, Subscript["V","dc"]}, -1,1},Delimiter,
  {{ctrlf, 10, "Frequency"}, 0.001,100},
  {{ctrlPhi, 0, "ϕ"}, 0, 2 π},
  ControlPlacement->Left, Paneled->True]
```

I would like to use the `Manipulate` as an editor that sets the values of the variables in the code snippet above and then passes them on as parameters to a function along with other sets of variables.

Is there a way to add a button to save the current values to a dataset?

Comment: Possibly [related](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/15090/7167)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think I have it this time:

Here's the `Manipulate`, I removed the `Module` and cleaned up the `Symbols` a bit

```
Manipulate[(*Function*)
  Plot[ctrlVdc + ctrlVac ctrlgFunc[2 Pi ctrlf t + ctrlPhi], {t, 0, 0.4}], 
  {{ctrlgFunc, Sin, ""}, {Sin, Cos, Tan, Cot}}, 
  Delimiter, 
  {{ctrlVac, 1.5, Subscript["V", "ac"]}, -10, 10}, 
  {{ctrlVdc, 0.5, Subscript["V", "dc"]}, -1, 1}, 
  Delimiter, 
  {{ctrlf, 10, "Frequency"}, 0.001, 100}, 
  {{ctrlPhi, 0, "ϕ"}, 0, 2 π}, 
  Delimiter, 
  Button[
    "Store", 
    d = Dataset[Association @ 
          {gFunc -> ctrlgFunc, Vac -> ctrlVac, Vdc -> ctrlVdc, 
           ϕ -> ctrlPhi, ω -> 2 Pi ctrlf}]], 
  ControlPlacement -> Left, Paneled -> True]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

A `Button` has been added that, when pressed, creates a `Dataset`, d, that can be referenced outside of the `Manipulate`.

```
d
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: The OP seems to explicitly ask for a `Dataset` -- shouldn't be hard to update.

Comment: @MichaelE2 Completely missed that; thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: Thank you most kindly! This is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: Lastly, passing to a function *without* other parameters: `myfunction @@ Normal@d` or *with* other parameters `myfunction @@ Values@Normal@d~Join~{x, y, z}`. In both cases, it is beneficial to organize the dataset in the order needed for `myfunction`.

Comment: This is an excellent answer to a good question.  It has the virtue of simplicity.

Answer (score 2):

The following solution may or may not be too complicated to deal with, but it's kind of neat.  It uses [DynamicModule wormholes](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/AdvancedDynamicFunctionality.html#1497695040) to link variables between two `DynamicModules`.  One of the modules has to be created from within a live instance of the other one.  That is to say, you instantiate one (the parent) in the Front End, and it has to create the other (the child).  If the child is a `Manipulate` you have to use both options, `InheritScope -> True` and `LocalizeVariables -> False`. You then need to declare all the variables you want to use in the `Manipulate` into the parent `DynamicModule` or else they will be `` Global` `` variables.

In this setup, I have made the OP's `Manipulate` the child.  Whenever the variables are changed in the `Manipulate`, the parent `DynamicModule` has access to their values.  You can do with them as you please, including creating a `Dataset` if desired.  Just as a proof of concept, I have a button whose label dynamically shows the values of the variables in the `Manipulate`.  If the button is pressed, the global function `f` is called.  It does nothing if `f` is undefined, but it's there just to give the idea.  If you uncomment `Print@`, pressing the button will print the function call (which is shown below the image).

```
DynamicModule[
 {ctrlgFunc = Sin, ctrlVac = 1.5, ctrlVdc = 0.5, ctrlf = 10, ctrlPhi = 0},

 Button[
  Inactive[f][Dynamic@{ctrlgFunc, ctrlVac, ctrlVdc, ctrlf, ctrlPhi}], 
  (*Print@*)f[ctrlgFunc, ctrlVac, ctrlVdc, ctrlf, ctrlPhi]],

 Initialization :> {
   CellPrint@
    ExpressionCell[
     Manipulate[Module[{Vac, Vdc, ω, ϕ, f},
       Vac = ctrlVac;(*AC Voltage*)Vdc = ctrlVdc;(*DC Offset*)
       f = ctrlf;(*Frequency*)ω = 2 π f;
       ϕ = ctrlPhi;(*Phase Offset*)gFunc = ctrlgFunc;(*Function*)
       Plot[Vdc + Vac gFunc[ω t + ϕ], {t, 0, 
         0.4}]], {{ctrlgFunc, ctrlgFunc, ""}, {Sin, Cos, Tan, Cot}}, 
      Delimiter, {{ctrlVac, ctrlVac, Subscript["V", "ac"]}, -10, 
       10}, {{ctrlVdc, ctrlVdc, Subscript["V", "dc"]}, -1, 1}, 
      Delimiter, {{ctrlf, ctrlf, "Frequency"}, 0.001, 100},
      {{ctrlPhi, ctrlPhi, "ϕ"}, 0, 2 π}, 
      ControlPlacement -> Left, Paneled -> True, InheritScope -> True,
       LocalizeVariables -> False],
     "Output"]
   }
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

> ```
> f[Sin, 1.5, 0.5, 10, 0]
> ```

*Postscript*

Here's an `f` that yields a `Dataset`:

```
f[func_, vac_, vdc_, f_, phi_] :=
  output = Dataset[<|"func" -> func, "vac" -> vac, "vcd" -> vdc, "f" -> f,  "phi" -> phi|>]
```

#### Update - Variations

Having the `Manipulate` cell automatically created by `Initialization` may prove troublesome, which I hinted at rather obscurely above.  One variation would be to put the code in a button that would print the `Manipulate` in a cell whenever button was pushed.   In the OP's application, another variation that might be convenient would be to have an edit button that creates the `Manipulate` in a new dialog/palette.  All these approaches might allow the user to create multiple copies, which is probably not particularly desirable.  One can put in code to block the check whether a `Manipulate` is already displayed.  The following is one way to create palette.  Make the changes indicated in the following:

```
DynamicModule[
 {ctrlgFunc = Sin, ctrlVac = 1.5, ctrlVdc = 0.5, ctrlf = 10, ctrlPhi = 0, 
  editpalette},

 Column[{
   Dynamic @ Dataset[<|"func" -> ctrlgFunc, "vac" -> ctrlVac, "vcd" -> ctrlVdc,
       "f" -> ctrlf, "phi" -> ctrlPhi|>],
   Button[
    "edit",
    If[! MemberQ[Notebooks[], editpalette], 
     editpalette = CreatePalette[
       Manipulate[..., InheritScope -> True, LocalizeVariables -> False],
       Saveable -> False
       ]]
    ]
   }]
 ]
```

Comment: @m_goldberg It's mentioned in the text.  Or hidden in the definition of `f`. :)  I primarily responded to "I would like to use the Manipulate as an editor that sets the values of the variables in the code snippet above and then **passes them on as parameters to a function** along with other sets of variables."

Comment: @m_goldberg  I had actually already written `f`, but decided to leave it out.

Comment: This is very good information and starts to address some design pattern questions I have been considering.  While a Model layer in the classic MVP or MVC Design Pattern could be implemented in earlier versions, the new Dataset makes this more accessible.  This line of thought would be another question and from the existing posts, I see some very good thoughts around design patterns are already here.  Thank you very much for the code sections and discussions above - extremely helpful.

Comment: @user1585715  You're welcome.  As you move ahead, you may find it easier to construct sophisticated interfaces with `DynamicModule` instead of `Manipulate`.  `Manipulate` constructs a `DynamicModule` automatically, and the automatic things it does can be either conveniences or obstacles.  You'll find some debate on this site about which to use.  For small, simple things, I find `Manipulate` quite convenient.  Others who develop applications for clients usually need `DynamicModule`.