# any way to store the values of the controls of a Manipulate so that one can reuse them in the future excutions

Tags: list-manipulation, manipulate, assignment, head

I’m using Manipulate[] to adjust several parameters, which will eventually generate some figures. After I get the desired view, I’d like to store the set of control parameters so that I can reuse them in the future.

Currently, I created two controls “recordControlParameters” and “userecordControlParameters” as flags, to let the code print out the list of control parameters as a list, and then paste their values to an assignment of these parameters at the beginning of the module, which could work, but the problem is, next time when I execute this code, I can no longer adjust any of these parameters if I turn on the “userecordControlParameters” mode.

I hope to find a way to be able to skip the assignment at the beginning of the code. For example, if I want to still adjust {b,c}, then I hope that, once I’m given this list at the beginning, I can skip the assignment of them.

**The essense of this question is: given a list allvariables={a,b,c,d},variables2skip={b,d} and valueList={1,2,3,4},  with a,b,c,d already assigned to some nuemrical values by the control itself, how can we reassign a and c upon using allvariables and variables2skip and valueList?**

Or is there any more elegant ways to cope with this?

Below is a minimal example (the real code has a large number of controls)

```
DynamicModule[{a, b, c, d, e, g, userecordedControlParameters, 
recordControlParameters}, 
Manipulate[
Module[{}, 
If[userecordedControlParameters == 
 1, {a, b, c, d} = {1, 2, 3, 0}]; 
If[recordControlParameters == 1, Print[{a, b, c, d}]];   
Plot[a*x^3 + b*x^2 + c*x + d, {x, -4, 4}]], 
Evaluate@manipulateControlLayoutUsingDivider[
 "Row"]@{Style["Amplitudes Sines", 15, Bold], {{a, 1, "a"}, 0, 
  3}, {{b, 1, "b"}, 0, 3}, Delimiter, 
 Delimiter, {{g, 1, "g"}, 0, 10}, Delimiter, {{e, 2, "e"}, 0, 5}, 
 Delimiter, {{c, 1, "c"}, 0, 4}, {{d, 0, "d"}, 0, 2}, 
 Delimiter, {{recordControlParameters, 0, 
   "recordControlParameters"}, {0, 
   1}}, {{userecordedControlParameters, 0, 
   "userecordedControlParameters"}, {0, 1}}}, Alignment -> Center,
 ControlPlacement -> Left]]
```

[image]

Comment: I think the best way to achieve what you want would be to manually add your preferred values to the [`Initialization`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Initialization.html) option within `Manipulate`.

Comment: Did you try the bookmarks-feature? You can click the plus on the upper right corner to save and restore parameter th values. It's not as flexible as what you are asking for in the question, but maybe it's enough?

Comment: You can Bookmark a setting with the + popup menu in the upper right corner of a `Manipulate`. Possible duplicate: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/17988 -- I do this for classroom demonstrations. Also related: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/56368

Comment: There is also a `Paste Snapshot` command in bookmarks menu, which may be sufficient for your purposes.  It pastes a `DynamicModule` that constructs the `Manipulate` body without the controls or surrounding panel. (For that matter, `Add to Bookmarks...` from the bookmarks menu may be what you're looking for. Beware that those are saved in the `Manipulate` and go away if the cell is deleted or overwritten.)

Comment: See http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Bookmarks.html

Comment: Sorry, things keep coming up in my mind. Let me know if any of these ideas work for you: Put this right after the `Manipulate` output after you have saved some bookmarks to retrieve the saved the `Bookmarks` option setting. You can then edit them and add the edited `Bookmarks` option to `Manipulate`.  A `Bookmarks` setting does not have to set all controls. So you could have `Bookmarks -> {"Setting 1" :> {a = 2; c = 7}}` that skips `b`, `d` etc.

Comment: sorry for the late reply, I had been overwhelmed with some urgent work these days, and just had the chance to come back to this issue. The Bookmark option is exactly what I'm looking for; after I paste the bookmark, I can add it as an option of Manipulate, then I can retrieve the status of the controls later on. Moreover, I can further  change  the values of any of the controls. These are all I need.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't used this myself, but it looks like the [SaveDefinitions](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SaveDefinitions.html) option is what you want, if I understand you correctly...? `Manipulate` also has some other options that look helpful, like [UnsavedVariables](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/UnsavedVariables.html) for those values you want overwritten each time.

Failing that, you're probably looking at doing the saving/loading manually using something like [PersistentSymbol](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PersistentSymbol.html); you would write out to `PersistentSymbol["myDataWhatever"]` whenever the settings changed and/or you wanted to save their values, and then you can access that data again even in a later session, so it's just a matter of loading up the right settings in `Initialization`.

Comment: thanks for your suggestion; I have checked out their documentation, but didn't catch what they are used for. Anyway, using bookmarks is sufficient for my current question.