# An issue regarding the use of CopyToClipboard with dynamic content

Tags: export, dynamic, evaluation, conversion

Please, consider the following code:

```
ColorSlider[
  Dynamic[x], ImageSize -> {800, 100}, AppearanceElements -> "Spectrum"
]

Button["get color",
 MessageDialog @ Dynamic[x];
 CopyToClipboard @ funct @ Dynamic[x];
]

Graphics[{Dynamic[x], Disk[]}, Frame -> True, FrameLabel -> Dynamic[x]]
```

To get the value of `RGBColor` in a string form, I have changed, in turn, the above `funct` with `OutputForm`, `StringForm` etc. obtaining always one of two results:

> ```
> Dynamic[x] (* or *)
>
> StandardForm  \!\(\*DynamicBox[ToBoxes[Global`x, StandardForm],
>  ImageSizeCache->{380., {2., 8.}}]\)
> ```

To track the issue I tried

```
 Slider[Dynamic[z]]

 Print @ Dynamic[z];

 Button["copy",
     MessageDialog @ Dynamic[z];
     CopyToClipboard  @ Dynamic[z];
 ]

 Button["paste",
     Paste  @ Dynamic @ z;
 ]
```

and understood that `CopyToClipboard` get the whole `DynamicBox`, not its 'current content'. How can I get rid of the "wrapper" ?

**Addendum**

I just have realized taht the color value can be read by means of

```
InputField[Dynamic[x]]
```

but it's evidently an expedient and doesn'  enlighten the broader subject.

Comment: So drop the `Dynamic` from the button. `Dynamic` is `HoldAll` so it stays this way untill it's displayed. `Button` is `HoldRest` so you will get the current value of `x` anyway. p.s. you can use `Setting` too.

Comment: closely related: [How to extract the numerical value of a dynamical variable](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/15090/5478)

Comment: Thanks for your reply ! `Setting` does perfectly the job. I'm going to study the other topics you mentioned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't found better duplicate so here's what you need to know:

from Mr. Wizard's answer to [Question about MapThread and Dynamic](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/5820/5478).

> In short, Dynamic doesn't do anything until it is actually displayed on screen.
>   Therefore, you are essentially doing this (note the String):

See also the linked topic.

Moreover, **in your case** `Dynamic[x]` takes the tour: `Button -> Clipboard -> final destination`. If you final destination is e.g. a MMA notebook, then the `FrontEnd` can handle this and will show you colored rectangle.

However, if you copy to let's say Notepad, you will get `Dynamic[x]`, with no info about `x` because `Dynamic` is `HoldAll`.

As I've mentioned the **workaround** is to use `Setting @ Dynamic @ x` [**[1]**](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/15090/5478) or just `x`, the `Button` is `HoldRest` so you will copy the current value of `x`.

[1]:  [How to extract the numerical value of a dynamical variable](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/15090/5478)

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I'm studying the sources you pointed at. Now I undestend the behaviour of this code: `Row @ {Slider[Dynamic[x]], Dynamic[x], Button["raw", Dynamic[x] >>> "deleteme.txt"], Button["value", Setting @ Dynamic[x] >>> "deleteme.txt"] 
}`